# R devtools unable to install - Ubuntu 20.04 - package or namespace load failed for ‘pkgload’

Tags: r, ubuntu, github, devtools

I am pretty desperate to `install.packages("devtools")`.
However it allways fails with this error

```
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pkgload', details:
  call: readRDS(nsInfoFilePath)
  error: error reading from connection
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/home/bjoern/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/devtools’
```

Things I tried to fix this:

1. Add the `dependencies = T` argument
2. Following a suggestion by hadley wickham on github -> update rlang package
3. Try to run `install.packages("pkgload")` resulting in nearly exactly the same error (see below)
4. Completely removing R and reinstalling it
5. Additionally installing package following packages:

   - r-base-dev
   - r-cran-devtools
   - r-recommended
6. Updated all packages update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)

Error of install.packages("pkgload")

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘pkgload’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pkgload', details:
  call: readRDS(nsInfoFilePath)
  error: error reading from connection
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
```

I digged even deeper to the [pkgload](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pkgload/index.html) (which at least I hope is the only reason for the problem). I will check if manually (re)installing all imports and suggests from the CRAN page of pkgload does solve it.

> **Imports:**  desc, methods, pkgbuild, rlang, rprojroot, rstudioapi,
>   utils, withr 
> **Suggests:**    bitops, covr, Rcpp, testthat

---

My `sessionInfo()` output:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3 tools_3.6.3
```

**I still refuse to belief that it is impossibe to install devtools on ubuntu20**
However at this point I take any straw

## Solution Edit:

In short what fixed the issue for me was installing testthat package before. Thanks to comment by [rui-barradas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8245406/rui-barradas)

```
install.packages("testthat") 
install.packages("pkgload") 
install.packages("devtools")
```

Comment: "I still refuse to belief that it is impossibe to install devtools on ubuntu20" Good! I know for certain it's possible to install `devtools` on Ubuntu 20.04 as I have it installed on 20.04! However, my R version is 4.0.0, so there might be some difference there. This seems like a potentially tough problem to debug. You may want to make sure there are no R packages installed (i.e., removing `r-cran-devtools` and any packages in your `/home/user/R/` folder), then start from **just** `install.packages("pkgload")`

Comment: @duckmayr Same here, Ubuntu 20.04/R4.0.0 all went so-so well. The problem is that I have to manually install each and every dependency that was already installed prior to 4.0.0. Meaning, before `pkgload` was installed I had to run `install.packages('testthat')`.

Comment: if/when you `apt-get install r-cran-devtools` (after adding Michael Rutter's PPA to your repository list as per the Ubuntu-specific instructions on the CRAN site), does it work?  That should be sufficient to install a binary version of the package (although I'd love to know why you're having trouble installing from source)

Comment: @RuiBarradas wow that fixed it. Just had to manually install `install.packages('testthat')` before. Now `pkgload` works as a charm and devtools was successfully installed as well. Looks like there is already an [issue](https://github.com/r-lib/pkgload/issues/89) on github for this

Comment: You want to wrap this up as an answer? As others might run into the same scenario? @RuiBarradas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I am also on Ubuntu 20.04 but running R 4.0.0.**

When trying to install a package, if it depends on another that was installed prior to R 4.0.0 I get an error message and the installation fails. This happens even if I set `dependencies = TRUE` in the call to `install.packages`.

**Example:** The command was

```
install.packages('pkgload')
```

I omit the first output lines, saying that the file was downloaded. Then, the relevant part.

> - installing *source* package ‘pkgload’ ...
>     ** package ‘rcmdcheck’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>     ** using staged installation
>     ** R
>     ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading   Error: package ‘testthat’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
>     Execution halted   ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘pkgload’
> - removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/pkgload’
> - restoring previous ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/pkgload’   Warning in install.packages :     installation of package ‘pkgload’ had
>     non-zero exit status      The downloaded source packages are in
>     ‘/tmp/RtmpVxpbs0/downloaded_packages’

**Correct way.**
The right way of installing package `pkgload` was to run the sequence

```
install.packages('testthat')
install.packages('pkgload')
```

and the problem was solved.

**Note** that with other packages, it already happened to see this be a recursive issue. Imagine that package `testthat` depended (which it does not) on another package installed prior to R 4.0.0.

Annoying but solvable.

```
sessionInfo()  
#R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)  
#Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)  
#Running under: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS  
#  
#Matrix products: default  
#BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0  
#LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0  
#  
#locale:  
# [1] LC_CTYPE=pt_PT.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C                
#[3] LC_TIME=pt_PT.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=pt_PT.UTF-8      
# [5] LC_MONETARY=pt_PT.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=pt_PT.UTF-8     
# [7] LC_PAPER=pt_PT.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                   
# [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C                
#[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_PT.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C           
#  
#attached base packages:  
#[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets   
#[6] methods   base       
#  
#other attached packages:  
#[1] rvest_0.3.5       xml2_1.3.2        data.table_1.12.8  
#
#loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problems, and the solution was, at least in my case, Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) + R 4.0.2:

First (from terminal), install:

Step 1:   sudo apt-get update -y
Step 2:   sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-dev

Then from RStudio (setRepositories first, and choose 8 repositories) and install both packages:

1. Install xml2 package
2. install devtools

And works for me.