# installing breakaway and loading packages

Tags: r, utf-8, namespaces

I tried to install the package breakaway in Rstudio (https://github.com/adw96/breakaway)

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("adw96/breakaway")
```

and got this error message:

```
Downloading GitHub repo adw96/breakaway@HEAD

Restarting R session...

Error: Unable to establish connection with R session
Loading required package: phyloseq
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘phyloseq’:
 package ‘utf8’ does not have a namespace
Error in .requirePackage(package) : 
  unable to find required package ‘phyloseq’
Loading required package: phyloseq
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘phyloseq’:
 package ‘utf8’ does not have a namespace
Error in .requirePackage(package) : 
  unable to find required package ‘phyloseq’
Loading required package: phyloseq
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘phyloseq’:
 package ‘utf8’ does not have a namespace
Error in .requirePackage(package) : 
  unable to find required package ‘phyloseq’
Loading required package: phyloseq
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘phyloseq’:
 package ‘utf8’ does not have a namespace
Error in .requirePackage(package) : 
  unable to find required package ‘phyloseq’
Loading required package: phyloseq
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘phyloseq’:
 package ‘utf8’ does not have a namespace
Error in .requirePackage(package) : 
  unable to find required package ‘phyloseq’
Loading required package: phyloseq
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘phyloseq’:
 package ‘utf8’ does not have a namespace
Error in .requirePackage(package) : 
  unable to find required package ‘phyloseq’
Loading required package: phyloseq
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘phyloseq’:
 package ‘utf8’ does not have a namespace
Error in .requirePackage(package) : 
  unable to find required package ‘phyloseq’
Loading required package: phyloseq
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘phyloseq’:
 package ‘utf8’ does not have a namespace
Error in .requirePackage(package) : 
  unable to find required package ‘phyloseq’
```

Everytime I try to load a package (phyloseq for instance), I get a related error message:

```
Erreur : package or namespace load failed for ‘phyloseq’:
 le package ‘utf8’ n'a pas d'espace de noms
Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : impossible d'ouvrir la connexion
Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : impossible d'ouvrir la connexion
```

How can I solve this?

Looking forward to your answers.

Comment: Looks like something is really wrong. Did you try restarting R or even RStudio?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R devtools unable to install - Ubuntu 20.04 - package or namespace load failed for ‘pkgload’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61643552/r-devtools-unable-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-package-or-namespace-load-failed-f)