# Styles changed for code in html from rmarkdown from an Ubuntu18/R3.5 environment to an Ubuntu20/R4.0 environment. Same files, different result

Tags: html, css, r-markdown

So I've got an RMarkdown script with an associated CSS file that's been working fine from an Ubuntu18/R3.5 environment. I've got it over to a Ubuntu20/R4.0 environment now, and even though the Rmd and CSS files are the exact same, the code styles have changed!

Example of markdown code :

````
This report has been created for reproducibility, using **`Rmarkdown`**, publicly available **`R`** packages, and the **`LaTeX`** document typesetting software. Packages and their version numbers are listed below.

\fontsize{8}{12}

```{r sessionInfo, eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE, comment=NA}
options(width = 100)
utils:::print.sessionInfo(sessionInfo()[-7], locale=FALSE)
```
The session data produced in the production of this report, which can be used for further analysis of the dataset, can be found here:
~~~
`r persistenceData`
~~~
````

Used to give me:

[image: before]

Now gives me:

[image]

As you can see the in-text code has now changed to what the block code was, and the block code background has turned white.

CSS:

```
 html{font-family:arial;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}
 body{margin:0; font:arial;}
 article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,menu,nav,section,summary{display:block}
 a{background-color:transparent}
 a:active,a:hover{outline:0}
 abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}
 b,strong{font-weight:bold}
 dfn{font-style:italic}
 .title{margin-top: 0px;}
 h1{font-size:2em;margin:0.67em 0;color:#1F78B4}
 h2{font-size:1.5em;margin:0.67em 0;color:#A6CEE3}
 mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}
 small{font-size:80%}
 sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}
 sup{top:-0.5em}
 sub{bottom:-0.25em}
 img{border:0}
 svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}
 figure{margin:1em 40px}
 hr{-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;height:0}
 pre{overflow:auto solid #999;page-break-inside:avoid}
 code,kbd,pre,samp{background-color:gray; color:white; font-family:monospace, monospace;font-size:1em}
 button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{color:inherit;font:inherit;margin:0}
 button{overflow:visible}
 button,select{text-transform:none}
 button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer}
 button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default}
 button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}
 fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:0.35em 0.625em 0.75em}
 legend{border:0;padding:0}
 textarea{overflow:auto}
 optgroup{font-weight:bold}
 table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
 td,th{padding:0}
```

Any help would be fantastic. It's been a very long time since I've done CSS, and I'm baffled by this. From what I can see it still says background gray for code, so I guess newer markdown (or other package) has changed the style ID tag for code (???).

Comment: Have you tried starting from a fresh Rstudio session and save them as a new project? have you installed all the devtools for the Ubuntu20? [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61643552/r-devtools-unable-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-package-or-namespace-load-failed-f) had users report the same OS/R version as you, and had to make sure they installed ALL the dependencies, `install.packages("rmarkdown",dep=TRUE)`

Comment: Yeah, I've got all dependencies installed. Some I had to use `INSTALL_opts = "--no-lock"`, which was strange. I've found the problem and a work-around, which I'm writing into an answer. Would be great if someone could post a solid solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the root cause, and I'm posting this here as a work around. I will keep the question open for a bit in the hope that someone can give a proper solution better than my work around.

Inspecting the html file, I found that `pre:not([class]){background-color: white}` was masking the `pre{background-color: #808080}`. When I turned this off the problem went away.

[image: Problem]

So then I added `pre:not([class]){background-color: #808080}` into the CSS and the rmarkdown output is now how it was before. I know I'm not using `pre` properly here, and if the output was different this could throw up some nasty looking pages.

I also seperated `code` and `pre` to fix the in-text code, so now the in-text code is light grey with `pre:not([class])` masking the `code` background and text colours when in a block. Total hacky work around, I know...

```
 pre:not([class]){background-color: #808080}
 pre{background-color:#808080; color: white; overflow:auto solid #999;page-break-inside:avoid}
 code{background-color: #eee;border-radius: 3px;font-family: courier, monospace;padding: 0 3px;}
 kbd,samp{background-color:#808080; color:white; font-family:monospace, monospace;font-size:1em}
```